# phpsysinfo.conf IP address is invalid apache 2.2.22

Tags: apache, ip, wamp

After lots of search and new things learned as trying to solve my issue, I have to ask skilled people some advices !

**I setup Wamp 2.5 32bits on my Win 7 x64, thats comes withe Apache 2.4.9 and Php 5.5.12**
As I need to work on several websites **I set Virtualhosts** that are working pretty well. Each time I'm going back to those Apache and Php versions it's working, but sadly my website isn't running with these latests versions.

**One of my website is running on Apache 2.2.22_vc6_32bits and Php 5.2.17**, and I'm having trouble after setting up those as **Wamp stay on orange status**.
The full troubleshooting document on Wamp forum is telling (**httpd -t cmd**)  my problem is a **syntax error on line 22** of "[...]wamp/alias/phpsysinfo.conf :

**The specified IP address is invalid.**"

**Windows event viewer says same**.

I can't find how to ride off that issue, and I think not understanding everything, so **here is my phpsysinfo.conf** :

```
Alias /phpsysinfo "E:/Workingspace/wamp/apps/phpsysinfo3.1.12/" 

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#

<Directory "E:/Workingspace/wamp/apps/phpsysinfo3.1.12/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
</Directory>
```

**Wamp soft > Apache > Services > Test port 80** tells "Your port 80 isn't currently in use".

**Services.msc > wampmysqld** is running

**Services.msc > wampapache** isn't running, and if we try to start there an error message "....**could not start on local computer**, review Win event viewer. If this is a non Microsoft service contact... refer to service specific error code 1"

I'm fed up with all that and thanks anyone who will help me in anyway

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Apache 2.2.22 may not have been IPV6 aware, I cannot actually remember the version that first became IPV6 aware. Either that or you have set Apache to only listen on IPV4 in the httpd.conf file.

Anyway try removing the ::1 from this line so it looks like this

```
Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1
```

You may have to do this for all the Alias config files.

Answer (score -2):

As It turned out not working as well I decided to switch all the way to succeed. I uninstalled Wamp 2.5 to get only the Wamp 2.2d wich is having the good apache version so it doesn't mess up ! Thanks anyway for the hand !